# Using `broom:::glance` in a dplyr workflow with a single lm object fails

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

When I use `broom:::glance` in the following way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
mtcars %>% do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, .)) %>% glance(model)
```

I get

```
Error in complete.cases(x) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

However, when I add a `group_by`:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, .)) %>% glance(model)
```

does give the expected results:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 12]
Groups: am

  am r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic  p.value df logLik  AIC  BIC deviance df.residual
1  0     0.589         0.565  2.53      24.4 1.25e-04  2  -43.5 93.1 95.9    108.7          17
2  1     0.826         0.810  2.69      52.3 1.69e-05  2  -30.2 66.4 68.1     79.3          11
```

Am I missing something here, or is it an error in dplyr/broom?

Comment: Could this be related to a list of length 1?   `library(tidyr);unnest(list(mtcars, mtcars), gr) %>% group_by(gr) %>% do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, .)) %>% glance(model)` works

Comment: It indeed seems to be the case that it does not work when the output list of `do` is just a list of length one.

Comment: Good catch: it's because `do` on an ungrouped tbl_df doesn't return a `rowwise_df`, so the `glance.rowwise_df` method doesn't get applied. I've opened [an issue for this](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/issues/77) and will have it fixed shortly!

Comment: In the meantime, a not-too-ugly workaround is to group by a dummy column first: `mtcars %>% group_by(g = 1) %>% do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, .)) %>% glance(model)`. (Add `%>% ungroup() %>% select(-g)` to remove the dummy column after)

Comment: Thanks @DavidRobinson, I'll vote to close the question once you have the fix committed. Thanks again!

Comment: No need to close; I'll post as an answer after :)

Comment: Ok, that is even better @DavidRobinson. And it allows me to upvote you so you get some free internet points ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `do`, when performed on an ungrouped table, results in a `tbl_df` rather than a `rowwise_df`, meaning broom used a different method. I've [fixed this](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/issues/77) in the latest development version, such that you can now do:

```r
mtcars %>% do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, .)) %>% glance(model)
#>   r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic      p.value df    logLik
#> 1 0.7528328     0.7445939 3.045882  91.37533 1.293959e-10  2 -80.01471
#>        AIC      BIC deviance df.residual
#> 1 166.0294 170.4266 278.3219          30
```

I hope to have this up on CRAN (broom 0.4) soon, or you can install with `devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/broom")`. In the meantime, you could also use a temporary grouping column to get the desired behavior:

```r
mtcars %>%
    group_by(g = 1) %>%
    do(model = lm(mpg ~ wt, .)) %>% 
    glance(model)
#> Source: local data frame [1 x 12]
#> Groups: g
#> 
#>   g r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma statistic      p.value df    logLik
#> 1 1 0.7528328     0.7445939 3.045882  91.37533 1.293959e-10  2 -80.01471
#> Variables not shown: AIC (dbl), BIC (dbl), deviance (dbl), df.residual
#>   (int)
```